# How to get footer to stay at the bottom on both desktop and mobile

Tags: html, css

So when I set the footer's `position:absolute`;, it would stay at the bottom on mobile view; however, it will float in the middle of the page on desktop page. When I take it off, it would stay at the bottom on desktop page, and then float in the middle of the page on mobile view..

How would one would be able to correct this

Comment: whats your html and  css? You kinda leave us wtih a complete blank slate. Show us your code

Comment: Can you provide your code as its difficult to say what is causing this.  Its most likely to do with height of page.

Answer (score 0):

Give footer wrapper below css and you are done...

```
.foot-wrapper {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: I did that and if I set the css position to fixed, it would show up on the bottom on mobile view, but in the middle of the page on desktop view for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you want your footer at the bottom of the whole page, or want it like a "sticky" footer (you always wanna see the footer if you are at the middle of the page).

**The first solution (Footer at the bottom)**

***index.html***

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="some-content"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

***style.css***

```
.content-wrapper{
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:100px;
}
footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  /*your style after that*/
  width:100vw;
  height:100px;
}
```

**The second solution (For sticky footer)**

***style.css***

```
.content-wrapper{
  padding-bottom:100px;
}
footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  /*your style after that*/
  width:100vw;
  height:100px;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually want the footer to stay where it is, at the bottom of the page, not sticky footer. But for some reason when I set the position:fixed;, it would show up at the bottom on mobile view but in the middle of the page on desktop view.

Comment: @SarahCha Could you show some of your code then?